# Installing magick package in RStudio server

Tags: r, imagemagick

I used install.packages('magick') in RStudio Server. BUT it gave the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘magick’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-magick/00new/magick/libs/magick.so':
  /home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-magick/00new/magick/libs/magick.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Magick5Image5writeEPNS_4BlobERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEm
```

I think the problem is that different version used:

```
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6  
Using PKG_LIBS=-lMagick++-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
```

How can I change the same version? I think the ImageMagick-6 is installed. THANKS!
My R Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-x86_64/gcc-9.2.0/r-3.6.3-utjqqasrybg775sebpzql7gfnmtfwqey/rlib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-x86_64/gcc-9.2.0/r-3.6.3-utjqqasrybg775sebpzql7gfnmtfwqey/rlib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be use the same version of Imagemagick, but it still showed error:

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘magick’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-magick/00new/magick/libs/magick.so':
  /home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-magick/00new/magick/libs/magick.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Magick5Image5writeEPNS_4BlobERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEm
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/magick’
```

And other information:

```
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6  
Using PKG_LIBS=-lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
```